# Aframe animation on button click

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

I am creating a web page using a-frame where on click of an image, a panel will show up.

On clicking the image the panel is visible, I have added an animation to change its Y-axis position as well.Unfortunately, the animation is not triggered. How can I achieve this ? I have provided the code i have tried so far below. I am new to a-frame and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>A-FRAME DEMO</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <a-scene>

    <a-assets>
    <img id="button" src="icons/button.png">
    </a-assets>

    <a-camera position="0 2 0"  wasd-controls-enabled="false">
    <a-cursor color="blue"/>
    </a-camera>

    <a-sky color="#FFF"></a-sky>

    <a-plane id="plane1" color="#000" height="4" width="20" position="0 0 -9" transparent="true" opacity="0.5" visible="false">
    <a-text value="Some Random Text." align="center" color="white" width="10" position="0 0 2" ></a-text>
    <a-image  id="cancel_tc" src="#cancel" position="9.5 3 0"></a-image>
    </a-plane>

    <a-image id="button_click" slidehandler1 src="#button" height="1" width="1" position="0 -1.6 -7"></a-image>

    </a-scene>

    <script>

    AFRAME.registerComponent('slidehandler1', {
    init:function() {
    var pln = document.querySelector("#plane1");
    this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pln.setAttribute('visible',true);
    //pln.setAttribute("position",{x:0,y:5,z:-9});
    pln.setAttribute('animation', 'property: position; dur: 1000; from: 0 0 -9; to: 0 5 -9');
    });
    }
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `animation` component came with a-frame 0.9.0. If you can, just switch to the newest build. If it's not possible, you'll need to include the [animation component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component).

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/wb1Lroxy/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate it when clicking using the mouse instead of the cursor, take a look at this component.  https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component